# disable specific additional keys with jquery

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Ive got a bit of a problem with users liking to enter random characters into a form i have set up.

Im trying to work out how to strip ¡™£¢∞§¶•ªªº––≠ characters from a string with either jquery or via the server side with coldfusion.

These keys are available after clicking on the alt / option key on my keyboard

Comment: i think this is different as its using the special keys and not just percentage or dollar signs

Comment: Decide what characters you want to allow and use a regular expression.  Alternatively, if you know for sure that you only want to allow characters below a specific ascii value, use that logic.